# IDE Crash causes hung job on Server

Tags: python, sql-server, spyder, pyodbc

Good Day All!  I am using pyodbc to connnect to a Microsoft SQL server using a Native Client 11.0 ODBC connection.  Occasionally something will happen to cause Spyder to crash resulting in my query to hanging on the server.  When this happens, all variables are lost, so I'm not able to cancel the job that is still on the server or close the connection.  My DBAs do not have rules in place to cancel long running queries, but hung queries like this block ETLs.  I have my ODBC connection set up the way they've requested, so the question is, what else can I do to prevent issues for my partners when Spyder crashes?  Note:  I've imported pandas as "pd".

```
try:
    data_conn = pyodbc.connect(dECTV)
    data_conn.timeout = 1000
    tfn = pd.read_sql(tele,data_conn)
    print("Call information retrieved") 
except:
    print('!~!~!~!n Exception has been Raised for Inbound information!~!~!~!')
    tfn = pd.read_csv(export_location + r'\TFN_Details.csv')       
finally:
    data_conn.close
    print("Connection Closed.  Moving on.")
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW, I've done a lot of reading over the last two hours and have what I consider to be a solution, but I wanted to see if others agree.  My thoughts would be to execute the following before running anything new on the same server.

```
exec sp_who 'my_login_id';  kill 'resulting_SPID';
```